# List : list all CLOS classes in a package

Tags: class, common-lisp, clos

I'm sure it's possible to list all classes defined in a package, but I don't know how to do it.

Does anybody have the answer ?

Thanks,

Comment: iterate `FIND-CLASS` over the package symbols and collect the non-nil results.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  And knowing the class, is there a way to iterate on all its instances ?

Comment: no. not by default. But it is not hard to add...

Answer (score 4):

I've finally written this piece of code, that does what I needed :

```
(defun list-package-class (package)
  (let (classes) 
    (do-external-symbols (s (find-package package))
      (when (find-class s nil)
        (push s classes)))
    classes))
```